# Not pause thread using thread.sleep

Tags: java, multithreading

I have java listener. I receive data from client and the same time I do send some codes back. Below is snippet of my codes where I check is there is any pending codes to be send to device if there is it will keep trying to send for 5 times and after that it gives. I notice that once it send I call the Thread.sleep and this cause the thread to pause where I cant receive any data from the client and all my data fails and keep getting into the loop cause no acknowledgement

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        // TODO your request here
        //Select commandStatus 
        //check commandStatus if acked then is true else pause and repeat
        boolean success = true; // TODO change to whatever outcome of your
                                // request
        if (success) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000l);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                // TODO handle interruptions if applicable
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you tell the thread sleep, it can't do anything else.  That is the point.  If you want other things to run, they have to be in another thread, or you can't cause the thread to sleep.

Comment: More code is needed to provide a helpful answer. Calling sleep on a thread will cause it to "pause" for at least the time given in the argument (or until interrupted by another thread)

Comment: Probably you could use threads (from a threadpool for example) to retry or use Timer (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date)) to execute later.

Comment: I want to eliminate the pause such that after 10 seconds I want to check did I receive any ack on the message sent previously ?

Comment: @giorashc I have some more comments on the codes what I do after sending I want to come back in 10 seconds to check its status ?

Comment: Check its status may mean a lot of things. What exactly you want to check every 10 sec?

Comment: Basically you spin up a thread to wait for up to 10 seconds for something to happen and then get it to message your main thread back with a result (success and data or a fail (timeout). Google something about communicating between threads.

Comment: @giorashc I will first do something like this Select codeID,codeText from code where codeStatus='a'. Then for that codeText I send to client and after 10s I will check if the codeID the status is change to 's' else I keep sending. The problem now when I pause the 10s it might have send but the thread is pause so it never get to change its status.

Comment: The thread should continue running after it sleeps for 10s so just check the status after the sleep (although I recommend reading about common mechanisms for this kind of operations, i.e. client/server)

Comment: Yes I have checked it it running perfect every 10 seconds no issue on that. The problem when it goes to sleep is the problem and in between that time the client acknowledge the message and server never picked cause its sleeping ?

Comment: Is there any possiblility to set that during the sleep and if there any new data coming to wake it and reprocess it ?